# Recursive method for 2,4,8,..in java

Tags: java, recursion

I need to write an recursive method for my classes. The method should print the first n elements of the sequence 1,2,4,8,16,... so if the method is called for example like:

```
recSeq(6);
```

the method should print: 1,2,4,8,16,32
The method is declared like this:

```
static void recSeq(int n){

    //enter code here

}
```

I really don't know how to to it without a return value or something? Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a return value on the recursive method?

Comment: 1. check that `n > 1`, return if not. 2. call `recSeq(n - 1)`. 3. print `1 << n`.

Comment: So basically you're just asking us to do your homework for you. I will have to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive function.

```
void recSeq(int counter){
        if (counter <= 0 ) return; // first the exit condition
        int value = counter -1; 
        recSeq(value ); // go down to the bottom, in order to print values from lovest values to higher
        System.out.print(" "+(int)Math.pow(2, value )); // print the value
 }
```

on Exit:

```
 recSeq(6); //  1 2 4 8 16 32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void recSeq(int n){
    if(n > 1){
        recSeq(n-1)
        System.out.print("," + Math.pow(2, n-1));
    } else {
        System.out.print(1);
    }
}
```